# UITableViewCell delegate not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Conditions:

- Swift 4, Xcode 9.3
- Target: iOS 11.3
- UI Done Programatically
- Using Constraints
- `Episode` is an object that holds the `source` as a String

Situation:

Here is my custom cell: `EpisodeCell.swift`

```
import UIKit

protocol EpisodeCellDelegate {
    func didTapPlayButton(url: String)
}

class EpisodeCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: EpisodeCellDelegate?
    var episode: Episode!

    let cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "#EBE4D3")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let episodeTitle: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .darkGray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let playButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        btn.setTitle("PLAY", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup(){
        self.accessoryType = .none

        self.addSubview(cellView)
        cellView.addSubview(episodeTitle)
        cellView.addSubview(playButton)

        cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        episodeTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        episodeTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        episodeTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        episodeTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        playButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        playButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        playButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("initCoder has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func playPressed() {
        self.delegate?.didTapPlayButton(url: episode.source)
    }

}
```

And here is how I implemented on my View Controller with the tableview: `EpisodesViewController.swift`

```
extension EpisodesViewController: EpisodeCellDelegate {
    func didTapPlayButton(url: String) {
        print("WOAH: \(url)")
    }
}

extension EpisodesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "episodeCell")  as! EpisodeCell

        cell.episode = series.episodes![indexPath.row]

        cell.episodeTitle.text = ep.episodeName
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (series.episodes?.count)!
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I'm having difficulty in working the button to be tapped in a custom table view cell. My tableview conforms to the protocol but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried setting height and width constraint of the button?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is not a sufficient description of your problem. Please be more specific. In what way exactly doesn't your posted code work? Please [edit] your question (don't post a comment) with more details about your issue.

Comment: maybe another object on top of the button is preventing touch ?

Comment: @bseh when I did manually catch the tapping in the view controller, it catches it. So I'm thinking constraint is not a problem.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen, I thought so, but I caught it working when manually catching it in the controller.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `playPressed`. Did it get called when you tap the button?  Does it call the delegate method (ie, is delegate not nil?)

Comment: Also, it is a bit clunky for the cell to hold a reference to the episode. The cell,should pass itself to the delegate function so that the delegate can determine the row for the cell and access the episode from the data model.

Comment: @Paulw11, tried to have a breakpoint, no, it didn't go to the break point..   and yes, I can redo the reference issue

Comment: Try calling `setup()` when the view is ready: change your setup from `init()` to `awakeFromNib()`.

Comment: People, why the downvote? I've explained everything from my point of view, so if you can't answer this question then leave, nobody's forcing you to answer. My question made no sense if none answered correctly, but guess what, @Vinodh got an answer and he's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do lazy initialisation for control inside the tableviewcell. Below code does the magic for me.  Just change the below part of the code alone

```
lazy var cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    lazy var episodeTitle: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .darkGray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    lazy var playButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        btn.setTitle("PLAY", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .normal)
        btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()
```

Comment: You my friend, is a saviour!! How can this `lazy var` be working?

Comment: uicontrols should have weak reference to cell so lazy var does the job .

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have the action that a cell performs inside the cell.  Cells can be reused, and a cell that was in row 1 can end up in row 4 at any time. Instead of your playPressed() routine, use the traditional didSelectRowAtIndexPath call, which uses the IndexPath, not the cell itself, to determine the action to take.

Comment: Looks like he wants to split the cell's action from a specific button's action inside the cell. I've used something similar before, where tapping the cell's text "expands" it a little, but tapping a button will redirect to the full detail in a new view controller.